# Can I used SSL certificate on my testing/staging developement server?

Tags: magento-1.8, ssl, secure

I have to install **SSL certificate** on my domain but before that I want to test it on my **testing domain** which have same  so I can find out unknown error.

**Is it possible to  use it on testing domain first then used for main domain after that**?

I have hostgator basic **dedicated server** plan ..

```
 Intel E3-1220v3
 3.10 GHz Quad Core
 6 GB RAM
 1000 GB HDD in RAID 1
2 free IP
1 TB transfer
```

I have single domain certificate.

I want to do so because it may cause down website for unknown time

Answer (score 0):

No. I would suggest using Let's Encrypt as a free alternative to test or else you'll see common name issues which won't make test a representative comparison to live